# How do I split certain element within a list to create another list in python?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list below:

```
list = [' ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2 gh: 3', ' ik: 4']
```

From above list, I need something like below:

```
newlist = [' ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2', ' gh: 3', ' ik: 4']
```

So "list" contains 4 elements and then I need "newlist" to contain 5 elements.

Is there any way `split()` can be used here?

Comment: Are these leading spaces meaningful and required?

Comment: Even for quick example, try to avoid naming your variable with python [built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `list` !

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) in the following way:

```
import re

li = [' ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2 gh: 3', ' ik: 4']
newlist = []
for ele in li:
    match = re.findall(r"\w+\s?:\s?\d+", ele)
    newlist += [m for m in match]

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['ab: 1', 'cd: 0', 'ef: 2', 'gh: 3', 'ik: 4']
```

Comment: re.findall seems great to use. Can I use it in such a way to not make any modification to 1st element of my original list.

Comment: @Ab20, you mean you want to keep leading spaces?

Comment: For eg: if I have a list like this, list = ['first.t:  ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2 gh: 3', ' ik: 4']

Comment: and my new list should be like this: newlist = ['first.t: ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2', ' gh: 3', ' ik: 4']

Comment: I mean my 1st element in list, i.e. list[0] should not get modified

Comment: You can start the `for` loop from 2nd element, `for ele in li[1:]:` and initialize `newlist` as `newlist = [li[0]]`

Comment: oh ok, let me try

Comment: Check this: https://www.online-python.com/G4JNdPxFoq

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
newlist = []

for i in a:
    if len(i.split()) != 1:
        for key, val in zip(i.split()[::2], i.split()[1::2]):
            newlist.append(key + val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking method for the best.

```
list_name = [' ab: 1', ' cd: 0', ' ef: 2 gh: 3', ' ik: 4']
newlist = []
for value in list_name:
    if len(value) > 6:
        newlist.append(value[0:6])
        newlist.append(value[6:])
    else:
        newlist.append(value)
print(newlist)
```

as you can see, python have a great syntax called slicing (value[0:6])

if you learned about `range(start,stop,step)` you can use this as well `list_name[start:stop:step]`

the empty value will automaticaly set into the default `[0,-1,1]`

have fun :)